# Why does my home server freeze?

Tags: freeze, ubuntu-12.04, home-server

My brother just bought a new laptop and forgot about his old desktop. The desktop has a P17G Motherboard from PC Chips, 2GB RAM, a SATA hard drive, a PATA DVD-ROM, Pentium 4 with HT (Don't remember the model). I have an Ubuntu server installation on it. It works like a charm, but when a considerable amount of time has passed, the computer just freezes:

1. No video (Is headless, but I connected a monitor without results)
2. No network Access
3. Power is on.
4. CPU Fan is spinning

This is strange, if it were the CPU temperature it would just turn off. What do you think?

Comment: VSounds like the hardware is failing.  I would look at the hdd as the culprit.